# $C^{1}-curve$ has volume zero

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am doing the following problem.
Let $n>1$. Then the $\textbf{image}$ of the $C^{1}-curve$ $\gamma=(\gamma_1,....,\gamma_n)$,has n-dim volume (area if n=2) equal 0.

I am not getting what do mean by zero volume and how we will show it.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: The image of a curve is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus we can talk about its (Lebesgue) measure. Probably that's what it means by $n$-dim volume. Note that if we drop the $C^1$ assumption then this is not true, see [space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).

Comment: @freakish I got that volume 0 means that for $\epsilon>0$ there is a  countable covering (finite) by balls .Can you give me hint about this covering

Comment: For every $t\in[0,1]$ and every $\epsilon>0$ there is a small interval $[t_1,t_2]\ni t$ covering it such that the curve $\gamma|_{[t_1,t_2]}$ can be put inside a cylinder of radius $\epsilon$, height $\leq$ length of $\gamma|_{[t_1,t_2]}$. Since $\gamma([0,1])$ is compact you can cover it by finitely many of those cylinders. The total volume of those cylinders is not larger than $\pi\epsilon^2\times$ length of $\gamma$.